# Can't get java version using process standard output (VB.NET)

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, process, output

I need to get java version, so i need java process with parameter "-version"

it works on cmd, and not work on this code.
and, it create java process well. but i can't get output.

What i need to solve this problem?

```
    Dim JavaProc As New Process()
    Dim JavaProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("java", "-version")

    With JavaProcInfo
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    End With

    With JavaProc
        .StartInfo = JavaProcInfo
        .Start()
    End With

    Dim sOutput As String
    Using sReader As System.IO.StreamReader = JavaProc.StandardOutput
        sOutput = sReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    MsgBox(sOutput)
```

Comment: The problem is most likely that java is most likely terminating before you can grab the output.  You might be able to resolve it by handling the OutputDataReceived event to get the output as it happens and before java exits.  You might also try calling cmd.exe instead, passing java as the argument.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway i tried add P.WaitForExit() before get stream, and after get stream. but it doesnt work too. i tried shutdown instead java, it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version is sitting on the StandardError stream.  Below is the modified code block; notice that the StandardError stream needs to be redirected.

```
Dim JavaProc As New Process()
Dim JavaProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("java", "-version")

With JavaProcInfo
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .RedirectStandardError = True
End With

With JavaProc
    .StartInfo = JavaProcInfo
    .Start()
End With

Dim sOutput As String
Using sReader As System.IO.StreamReader = JavaProc.StandardError
    sOutput = sReader.ReadToEnd()
End Using

MsgBox(sOutput)
```